# Unable to read excel file(.xls) in java poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Trying to use the Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileName)); // Read the xls file found on the below link

Tried some other libraries jxcel, no luck, Can someone help if am doing anything wrong

XLS files : https://www.huduser.gov/portal/datasets/excel/wy_foreclosure.zip

**Code:**

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
.......
......

try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
                Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(fileName));) {

        }
```

**Exception Trace :**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.util.RecordFormatException: Not enough data (0) to read requested (2) bytes
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordInputStream.checkRecordPosition(RecordInputStream.java:243)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordInputStream.readShort(RecordInputStream.java:262)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.PrintSetupRecord.<init>(PrintSetupRecord.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory$ReflectionConstructorRecordCreator.create(RecordFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createSingleRecord(RecordFactory.java:345)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactoryInputStream.readNextRecord(RecordFactoryInputStream.java:288)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactoryInputStream.nextRecord(RecordFactoryInputStream.java:254)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordFactory.createRecords(RecordFactory.java:494)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:344)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(HSSFWorkbookFactory.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:314)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createHSSFWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:292)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:128)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:281)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:253)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:234)
    at com.noteunlimited.util.ForeClosureDump.generateStatistics(ForeClosureDump.java:55)
    at com.noteunlimited.util.ForeClosureDump.main(ForeClosureDump.java:64)
```

Comment: Could you get whoever created those xls files to check that they are saving them properly? Those files in the the zip do not appear to be standard xls format. If there are xlsb format, you might be able to use https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/binary/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

To open an existing XLS file you can e.g. use this code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class OpenXLS {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("yourFile.xls"));
    // Do something with it.
    workbook.close();
  }
}
```

This won't work with the files you provided. But when you open one of these files in LO Calc and save it without any changes made then everything is fine. So, something seems to be not right with your files.

Comment: Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xlrd 
>>> loc = "~/Downloads/IL_County.xls"
>>> wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
WARNING *** file size (38194) not 512 + multiple of sector size (512)
WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero
>>> sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
>>> sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 
u'countycode'
>>> sheet.cell_value(1, 0) 
u'17001 // It was working with  python

Comment: I have no idea about the binary XLS format, sorry. It may be that this is a [tough problem](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Not-enough-data-1-to-read-requested-2-bytes-File-succeeds-on-saving-using-excel-td5721954.html).

Comment: Has there been a successful way to read the xls file? Is fixing the xls file the only solution here?